# Overriding fromInteger in Haskell

Tags: haskell, numeric, typeclass

So I like Haskell, but am dissatisfied with the Num class.
So I want to make my own typeclass hierarchic for algebraic types.
The problem is, even if I import Prelude hiding Num and everything associated with it, still the only way to make the literal 1 have type t is to make t instance Num.
I would love to make my own fromInteger class and leave Num out of the picture entirely, like this

```
import Prelude hiding (everything having to do with Num)
import qualified Prelude (everything having to do with Num)

class (Eq fi) => FromInteger fi where
  fromInteger :: Integral -> fi

foo :: (FromInteger fi) => fi -> String
foo 1 = "that was a one"
foo 0 = "that was a zero"
foo n = "that was neither zero nor one"
```

and then I would implement fromInteger appropriately for brand new types and never have to say anything about Num.

Is there a way to tell the parser to use a different fromInteger method?

Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are looking for GHC's [RebindableSyntax extension](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/users_guide/syntax-extns.html#rebindable-syntax).

Enable it by putting

```
{-# LANGUAGE RebindableSyntax #-}
```

at the top of your source file.

Comment: @JosephVictor Do look at the [Numeric Prelude](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Numeric_Prelude) as well. You may find it does what you want.