# No instance for (Num Nat) arising from the literal ‘1’

Tags: haskell, numbers, instance

I am trying to create some functions using natural numbers.

```
import Prelude
data Nat = Zero | Succ Nat

add:: Nat -> Nat -> Nat
add Zero n = n
add (Succ m) n = Succ (add m n)

mult :: Nat -> Nat -> Nat
mult x Zero = Zero
mult x (Succ y) = add x (mult x y)
```

then when I run

```
mult 3 5
```

I get this error:

```
<interactive>:38:6: error:
• No instance for (Num Nat) arising from the literal ‘3’
• In the first argument of ‘mult’, namely ‘3’
  In the expression: mult 3 5
  In an equation for ‘it’: it = mult 3 5
```

I am relatively new to Haskell so any help would be appreciated. 
Thanks in advance

Comment: But `3` is not a `Nat`. Here you defined it as `Succ(Succ(Succ(Zero)))`...

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem, but I thought a Natural number was a positive integer?

Comment: Yes. It is, but why do you expect Haskell to autmatically map number literals on `Nat`s you define yourself?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How is the compiler supposed to know that `Zero` is intended to represent the number `0`, as well as `Succ . Succ $ Zero` the number `2` and so on? It would have to more or less *blindly guess* that this is what you intend.

You can explicitly tell it to handle number literals this way, though:

```
instance Num Nat where
  fromInteger 0 = Zero
  fromInteger n = Succ . fromInteger $ n - 1
```

Furthermore, even if the compiler thus knows how `Nat`s can be *defined* through number literals, it won't be able to *display* a given/computed `Nat` value. For that, there is a natural automatic fix, though:

```
data Nat = Zero | Succ Nat
   deriving (Show)
```

You can also add [`Eq`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base/docs/Prelude.html#t:Eq), [`Ord`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base/docs/Prelude.html#t:Ord) <del>and [`Enum`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base/docs/Prelude.html#t:Enum)</del> to the `deriving` list; <del>in fact the derived `Enum` instance does pretty much that “blind guessing” as to what `Nat` value represents what number.</del> Actually I've just noticed that `Enum` can't be derived on recursive types like `Nat`; if that were possible you *could* write:

```
instance Num Nat where
  fromInteger = toEnum . fromInteger
```

Comment: Thanks, I was following some example from a book. I think I missed a key step somewhere.

Comment: @ThomasCrowley Great answer. One quibble though: `Num` has other members that can't be implemented properly for `Nat`, which could lead to runtime crashes if the OP isn't careful.

Comment: You surely wouldn't want to define `fromInteger` using `toEnum` anyway, as the latter will break beyond `maxBound :: Int`.

Comment: @dfeuer you wouldn't want to express a number anywhere near `maxBound :: Int` in Peano arithmetic anyway, though...

Comment: @leftaroundabout, what if it's a lazy over-estimate?

Comment: @dfeuer then it shouldn't be expressed as any particular integer literal, but as `fix Succ`.

Comment: Which, incidentally, is exactly what would happen after an overflow to negative with a naïve definition.

Answer (score 3):

**TL;DR**

GHC is telling you exactly what you need to know: that your `Nat` type is not in fact an instance of `Num`. This is the typeclass that allows integer literals to be polymorphic (via `fromInteger`).

---

Integer literals in Haskell are polymorphic, so `mult 3 5` *could* work. The problem is that you haven't explained how to turn `3` and `5` into `Nat`s.

The most straight-forward way of solving the problem is to implement `Num` for your type. You could also create a separate `natFromInteger` if you don't wish to implement the entire set (such as subtraction, which is a partial function for natural numbers).

**`Num` solution**:

```
instance Num Nat where
  fromInteger 0 = Zero
  fromInteger n = Succ . fromInteger $ n - 1
```

You could simplify the solution via `fromEnum` as @leftroundabout suggests.

**A free standing `natFromInteger` solution looks about the sam**e:

```
natFromInteger :: Integer -> Nat
natFromInteger 0 = Zero
natFromInteger n = Succ . natFromInteger $ n - 1
```

This solution will not let you convert literals implicitly. On the other hand, it avoids the issue of having partial or unimplemented functions, as I mentioned before.

**A compromise: RebindableSyntax**

There is a third option, which let's you *override* `fromInteger` without implementing the remaining litany of mathematical functions and operators from `Num`: using the GHC extension `RebindableSyntax`. Have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13978395/overriding-frominteger-in-haskell) for details.